# Scheduling a Jenkins job with extended choice parameters

Tags: jenkins, scheduling

I have a job with extended choice parameters. I have specified the parameters in a property file. Now I want to schedule a job with parameters specified in the property file, but I can not do this. I am using a cron entry like:

```
35 11 * * 1-5 % States=Massachusetts
```

`States` is a parameter name and `Massachusetts` is a value from the property file. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Freestyle project job, and set the cron line in that job, then you add a build step that triggers the job you want to run and there you can pass your custom parameters, personally I use the predefined parameters, after that you have something like this

[image: Build steps]

Where "test" is your job's name, and the params

```
STates=Massachusetts
```